# ADFS custom authentication provider metadata mismatch

Tags: c#, saml, adfs, adfs4.0, multi-factor-authentication

i have created a custom  Authenticator for `ADFS` MFA. i have defined authentication methods in metadata :

```
 class MyMetadata : IAuthenticationAdapterMetadata
    {
        public virtual string[] AuthenticationMethods
        {
            get { return new[] { 
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp" }; }
            }
}
```

also my TryEndAuthentication is defined as:

```
   public IAdapterPresentation TryEndAuthentication(IAuthenticationContext context, IProofData proofData, HttpListenerRequest request, out Claim[] claims)
        {
            claims = new Claim[0];
            //return new MyPresentationForm();
            System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp");
            claims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { claim };
            return null;

        }
```

But i am getting this error in ADFS log:

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
gitlab-app 

Exception details: 
System.IO.InvalidDataException: The authentication provider returned authentication method http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp, which is not specified as a supported authentication method in the provider's metadata.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.External.ExternalAuthenticationHandler.ValidateAdapterClaims(IAuthenticationContext authContext, ICollection`1 claims, Int32 responseLcid)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.External.ExternalAuthenticationHandler.ProcessAdapterClaims(ICollection`1 claims, AuthenticationContext authContext, ProtocolContext context, IAccountStoreUserData userData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.External.ExternalAuthenticationHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.AuthenticationOptionsHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

You have to change the http to https: https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp

**But do not change this url http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod**

[stackoverflow AAD FS custom authentication provider did not return an authentication method claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945328/ad-fs-custom-authentication-provider-did-not-return-an-authentication-method-cla)