# AD FS custom authentication provider did not return an authentication method claim

Tags: c#, saml, adfs, multi-factor-authentication, claims-authentication

I have made a custom authentication provider for AD FS MFA.

I have defined an authentication method claim in the metadata:

```
public string[] AuthenticationMethods
{
    get { return new string[] { "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp" }; }
}
```

I also have an TryEndAuthentication method (this is only for lab purposes, I will change the hardcoded pin once this part works):

```
 public IAdapterPresentation TryEndAuthentication(IAuthenticationContext context, IProofData proofData, System.Net.HttpListenerRequest request, out System.Security.Claims.Claim[] claims)
    {
        claims = null;
        IAdapterPresentation result = null;
        string pin = proofData.Properties["pin"].ToString();
        if (pin == "12345")
        {
            System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp");
            claims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { claim };
        }
        else
        {
            result = new AdapterPresentation("Authentication failed.", false);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But when i deploy this in my AD FS it gives me this error when i sign on correctly:
[image: The Authentication provider did not return an authentication method claim]

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of AD FS you used for your adapter?

Comment: I work with Windows Server 2019 AD FS. Do you mean that my adapter .NET framework might be incompatible with my .NET framework on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The URI for the schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod claim should use http. Not https.

You should change below line

```
if (pin == "12345")
        {
            System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp");
            claims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { claim };
        }
```

to

```
if (pin == "12345")
        {
            System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", "https://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp");
            claims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { claim };
        }
```

and then it will work.

I made this same mistake when I copied the sample adapter code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-build-custom-auth-method

I have submitted the https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/pull/4165 correction on github which should get committed soon.